# What is the preferred, secure method of exposing docker services to a web application?

Tags: docker

I'm just getting into Docker and it's great and everything, but one part confuses me. I'm using a docker image to encode video, and the image can be run like a command with `docker run my/image -flag param1` etc. I also happen to be using Apache as my web server. Let's say I want to allow a user to upload a video, so I process the upload with PHP, and I want to use PHP to run the docker image as a command via `exec`. The problem is that docker can only be run as root/sudo, so by default an `exec` command fails because the `www-data` user is not root and therefore does not have privileged access to run `docker` commands. I could add `www-data` to the docker group, but I've read that is a poor choice in terms of security. What is the approach I should be taking to utilize this docker image and expose its functionality to a web application?

Comment: See [Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user (Rootless mode)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) or take a look at tools like [podman](https://podman.io/) that do not require root access. --- I would strongly advice against such an approach. It would be better if we had a container running that we can "trigger" (e.g. through a REST interface) to encode the video.

Comment: Is there some way to extend the original image with RESTful functionality without recreating it from scratch?

Comment: I do not know. I have not taken a look at the docker image.

Comment: For example, if running the docker image simply produces an output. Can I write a new dockerfile that implements the base to wrap RESTful services around it?

Comment: This should generally be possible, yes. That is what the [`FROM` statement in a `dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) is for: start with an already existing image, add something on top of it.

Comment: What if I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116144/how-do-i-run-apache-as-root) technique to expose pre-constructed docker commands via bash script + specific arguments, rooted specifically for the Apache user? Any glaring security holes there?

Answer (score 1):

it is definitely possible but it's not recommended as Docker was not designed for that purpose. Docker is not a distributed task system so you will got a lot of problems to make sure that your task is delivered to proper worker or you will have to implement your self the mechanism to retry failed/crashed tasks. Instead, I think you can try Cadean from Uber https://github.com/uber/cadence on top of Docker (Docker is for deployment and Cadean for task distribution).

We also have a video processing system and we are using Celery (Cadean is very new at the time we started the project) for task distribution (we are using Docker for deployment too). And it is working well until now.

If you still would like to execute every Docker container per task. You can try Docker Engine API https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/ instead of using CLI interface to prevent granting execute permission to `www-data`. But again, you will expose all Docker capabilities to the web user as Docker has no authorization method to limit API access per user, so attackers can start a container and mount to root to modify your system files. In short, it is possible but not a good practice just because Docker is not designed to do that.